# graphQL: SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I started learning some GraphQL and so far in the Playground everything works great. no issues with it.

I do have some issues while querying Apollo Server. I am not entirely sure what's causing the issue but I suppose I am not sending the correct payload to the server.

app.js

```
import { ApolloClient, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query TestQuery {
      hello {
        title
      }
    }
  `,
});
```

Server:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Obj {
    title: String
  }

  type Query {
    hello: Obj
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => ({ title: 'hello' }),
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(() => {
  console.log('Server is running! Listening on port 4000');
});
```

Playground:

[image: playground]

Client:

[image: client]

I am also sharing the body of the request (which seems to be a string)

```
{"operationName":"TestQuery","variables":{},"query":"query TestQuery {\n hello {\n title\n __typename\n }\n}\n"}
No properties
```

I think the request body is a string but I am not sure what could cause the issue. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: bad (not json) response, bad (not the same) query

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: check raw network response ... auth/cors?